# What effect does the size of the soma have on firing characteristics?

Tags: neuroscience, theoretical-neuroscience, neuroanatomy

For example, cells in layer 5 of the neocortex have a larger soma than do other layers. I'm wondering what the functional difference is between smaller and larger soma. On one hand, I can imagine that there's more area for axo-somatic synapses (making the neuron easier to fire). On the other hand, it's a larger cell and thus requires more simultaneous synaptic activations. Thanks!

Comment: All axo-somatic synapses in the neocortex (and I think in the CNS generally, but my expertise is mostly in neocortex) are inhibitory.